# Replace white space in .csv for specific column, Python

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, whitespace

I have a seemingly simple task with a .CSV file. I need to replace all white space with 0's for two specific columns (37, 38). I've tried the following code:

```
import csv

with open("C:/Temp/whiteSpace.csv", "rb") as infile, open("C:/Temp/repaired_test.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
        row[37] = row[37].replace(' ', '0')
        writer.writerow(row)
        print row[37]
```

However, this simply writes the "whiteSpace.csv" over to "repaired_test.csv" with out editing anything.

I've found plenty on stripping whitespace ([strip white spaces from file csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885908/strip-white-spaces-from-file-csv)) but I'm not able to connect the dots and make my code work.

Sorry for the redundant question, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the character you want to replace is the blank character ()? It could be a tab or something else. You can try a regex to catch all blank chars:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'\s')
>>> r.sub('0', 'TEXT\tSPACE TEXT')
'TEXT0SPACE0TEXT'
```

Comment: Well, more specifically, I need to replace blank values (different from white space?). Eventually I need to do a join, but the blank values in the column cause the script to get hung up.