# Copy specific rows from csv to csv in Python 2.7

Tags: python, csv

So far I have been trying to copy specific rows including headers from original csv file to a new one. However, once I run my code it was copying a total mess creating a huge document.

This is one of the options I have tried so far, which seems to be the closest to the solution:

```
import csv
with open('D:/test.csv', 'r') as f,open('D:/out.csv', 'w') as f_out:
     reader = csv.DictReader(f)
     writer = csv.writer(f_out)
     for row in reader:
         if row["ICLEVEL"] == "1":
            writer.writerow(row)
```

The thing is that I have to copy only those rows where value of "ICLEVEL"(Header name) is equal to "1".

Note: test.csv is very huge file and I cannot hardcode all header names in the writer.

Any demostration of pythonic way of doing this is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any error? What's happening with your solution?

Comment: When I run it says "sequence expected"  and points at the last row. However, if I go with writer.writerow([row]) it makes a total mess.

Comment: can you give csv data example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `row` is a dictionary. CSV writer cannot write dictionaries. Select the values from the dictionary and write just them:

```
writer.writerow(reader.fieldnames)
for row in reader:
  if row["ICLEVEL"] == "1":
    values = [row[field] for field in reader.fieldnames]
    writer.writerow(values)
```

Comment: You did a great job. Can you suggest how to copy headers as well?

Comment: The first line of my snippet copies the headers.

Comment: Works for me in Python 2.7. How does it not work for you?

Comment: Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 4):

`writer.writerow` expects a sequence (a tuple or list). You can use `DictWriter` which expects a `dict`.

```
import csv
with open('D:/test.csv', 'r') as f, open('D:/out.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()  # For writing header
    for row in reader:
        if row['ICLEVEL'] == '1':
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for an effort, but it gave me a key error ['ICLEVEL'].

Comment: Yes, I just double checked it again :(

Comment: It should have worked. Could you put few sample rows of your CSV?

Comment: I just replaced my old csv with new one. It worked, however, it copies all the data, not specific one that I need.

Comment: There must be some whitespace around `row['ICLEVEL']`. It will be helpful if you add some snippet of your CSV.

Comment: Possibly, that's very interesting, I will try to make your solution work as well. Appreciate your assistance. Thank you!

Comment: Passing `skipinitialspace=True` to the reader might help in that case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885908/strip-white-spaces-from-file-csv

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use Pandas, not a CSV reader:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("D:/test.csv")
newdf = df[df["ICLEVEL"]==1]
newdf.to_csv("D:/out.csv",index=False)
```

The code is much more compact.

Comment: I am not allowed to use Pandas. Your previous answer was correct, I would appreciate if you could restore it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I see. I believe @Hussain's answer is actually better.

Comment: I appreciate his help, however, it didn't filter the data.